# Refresh page not found htaccess

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, ionic-framework, mod-rewrite

I have developed an ionic app and uploaded it to my apache server. However, when I refresh the page, I get that the index.html present in the root is refreshed and not the index.html present in the subfolder. 

My apache server structure:

index.html

api (folder)

database (folder)

myionicapp1 (folder)

myionicapp1/index.html

myionicapp2 (folder)

myionicapp2/index.html

myionicapp3 (folder)

myionicapp3/index.html


So I have multiple subfolders of ionic projects.

The .htaccess file is in the root and has the following structure

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ myionicapp1/index.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ myionicapp2/index.html [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^ myionicapp3/index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I reload the pages in myionicapp1 and myionicapp2, everything works correctly, while if I reload myionicapp3 / index.html it brings me back to the root index.html.

When I enter myionicapp3, the url is as follows: https://www.mysite.example/myionicapp3/tabs/bar

Please, help me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. You need to put conditions like which URI should go to which index.html as of now there is NO condition it will create problems. If you could mention which URL should be server through which file then it will be easy for us to fix this one.

Comment: To clarify more which urls in backend should be served by index.html, which should be by index1.html and so on, if this is clear then we can handle it.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 , thanks for the reply. In fact I managed to solve it in this way. Redirect <current_url> to index1.html